# Instantiate a class on stack, where var is defined in header

Tags: c++, heap-memory, instantiation, stack-memory

I am currently trying to get into writing proper C++ code (getting it running was ok for some small prototypes, but it's been ugly).

I recently realized the difference of heap and stack instantiation (O  m = new O() vs. O m()).

Now I have a class, where the header file defines a variable, which holds an table definition.

> ChunkLoader.hpp:
>
> > > TablePartion *tablePartial_;
>
> ChunkLoader.cpp:
>
> > > ChunkLoader() { tablePartial_ = new TablePartial(true, 0, 1); }

Now I want to instantiate the tablePartial on the stack, but I cannot use:
`TablePartial tablePartial_(true, 0, 1);`

I am totally  blind? How can I allocate tablePartial_ on the stack?
Or I am getting it totally wrong, and I cannot use in the constructor since it would be out of scope after the constructor and thus be freed? But since I read that stack variables are better performance-wise, I'd like to use stack instantiation (and getting red of `delete`).

Main reason: stack overflow told me to get rid of pointers when ever possible. :)

Comment: Would you clarify what you mean by on the stack? Do you mean a local variable, or are you talking about passing constructor initializers to the parent class?  I am a little confused.

Comment: Is `tablePartial_` a member of the `ChunkLoader` class, or is it simple a variable in a function, or is it a global?

Comment: Beware, `O m();` has nothing to do with variables; it's a function declaration.

Comment: Edited my post to clarify. Right now, `tablePartial_` is a pointer to a TablePointer instance.
What I wanted to achieve was, that ChunkLoader persists `tablePartial_` on the stack.

@MooingDuck yes, tablePartial_ is a private member of ChunkLoader.

@FredOverflow I meant instantiating a Class O and calling the variable m (let's say the Constructor takes a boolean, so it would be `O m(true)` e.g.).

Comment: @Bouncner: Oh, if `tablePartial_` is a _pointer_, that _completely_ changes everything, and invalidates all existing answers.  Short story is either make the `TablePartion` a member itself (no pointer), or keep it on the heap.  A member pointer should almost never point to something on the stack.

Comment: Sorry for the typo in the comment. :(

I wanted to make tablePartial_ a member itself (what would be the case, if I could use `TablePartial tablePartial_();` on the ChunkLoader constructor).
But since I know now, that any member will be on the heap, if ChunkLoader will be on the heap, my question is kind of irrelevant now. :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To start off, you should probably avoid the terms "on the stack" or "on the heap", they're implementation details that have nothing to do with the concepts being discussed.  Instead, we discuss the lifetime of the object, in terms of `automatic` (which more or less correlates with the stack), `dynamic` (which more or less correlates with the heap), `static` (which more or less correlates with globals), and `thread` (which is a thread-specific global).

In answer to your specific question, you can use constructor initializers to initialize your variable:

```
ChunkLoader() 
   : tablePartial_(true, 0, 1) 
{ 
}
```

Comment: I upvote for correct solution though I don't agree with the first paragraph.

Comment: *shrug* Although only the first sentence is mine (more got added on later), it is a valid point. There are systems that have no stack yet can run C++ code just fine. I even programmed a C-ish compiler for a system like that (a stackless virtual machine).

Comment: This is actually wrong. If you do `ChunkLoader* p = new ChunkLoader`, `p` will be on the heap, and so will `tablePartial_`.

Comment: You're not answering the question: "How can I allocate tablePartial_ on the stack?".

Comment: @LuchianGrigore, Neither are you by your own definition. I would instead argue you're nitpicking for the sake of it, he obviously means "assuming the class itself is instantiated on the 'stack'".

Comment: @Blindy I just edited my answer. Also, I'm not nitpicking for the sake of it. It's just wrong to say that using an initializer list will put the class in automatic storage. And also, it doesn't change the fact that you're not answering the question.

Comment: @Mooing/Blindy Well I agree with the fact that it can be more complicated but I still think that heap and stack are important concepts.

Comment: First: as I commented on Luchian Grigore's answer, I misunderstood the fact, that tablePartial_ will end on the heap anyways, when ChunkLoader is on the heap (what it will be).

Second: thanks for the hint with the constructor initializer. It helped me getting the program compiling.

But how can I do that directly in the constructor? Let's say I am instantiating `tablePartial_` based on some constraints (if, else...).

Comment: @Bouncner, you can't really do that unless you call the default initializer on `tablePartial_` first, and **then** fill in the blanks in the constructor.

Comment: @Blindy: I thought of that, but I hoped there is a nice solution. Thanks for clearing that up!

Answer (score 1):

Since the class declaration is:

```
class MyClass
{
   SomeOtherClass x;
};
```

`x` is contained in `MyClass` completely (it's not a pointer to `SomeOtherClass`).

Ergo, when creating an object `MyClass` on the stack, `x` will also be on the stack, and when creating an object `MyClass` on the heap, `x` will also be on the heap.

EDIT:

As I understood it, you want to allocate `x` on the stack. To do this, any instance of `MyClass` must also be on the stack. For this, you can make the `new` operator `private`:

```
class MyClass
{
   SomeOtherClass x;
private:
   void* operator new(size_t);
};
```

Comment: This did not really my answer, but it clarified an important misunderstanding in my question. ChunkLoader is potentially persisting quite large data volumes (tens to hundreds Megabytes). As far I as know, this disqualifies for the instantiation on the stack.

When I understand you right, all class variables will be on heap, when the owning object is also on the heap. Since ChunkLoader will be on heap, I do not really have to care about tablePartial_.

Right?

Comment: @Bouncner: `tablePartial_` is a member, and so is wherever `ChunkLoader` is.  It is literally part of a `ChunkLoader`.  Like your stomach is part of you.  You shouldn't be worrying where it is.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't used the word "new" in C++ (avoiding malloc and other C/OS calls for this conversation), then you haven't dynamically allocated memory on the "heap".

Everything you create in main() and the functions called therein goes on the stack if new isn't used.  When you enter a new function call, you get a new stack frame, and all variables declared as so:

```
void foo() {
    int x;
    std::string y;
}
```

are created on the stack.

You can even get a "pointer" to a stack based object so you can use it polymorphically just like a pointer to a heap object:

```
//These should be "classes" with private/public hiding but I'm being lazy.
struct MyClass {
    int x;
    virtual void foo();
};

//These should be "classes" with private/public hiding but I'm being lazy.
struct MyClassDerived : MyClass {
    void foo() { std::cerr << "foo called!" << std::endl; }
};

int main() {
    MyClassDerived x;
    MyClass* = &x;
    x->foo();
}
```